# How to install multiple version of Kubectl on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, kubectl

I currently have kubectl v1.10.6 which I need to access my cluster, however I'm also trying to connect to a different cluster thats running on v1.5.

How and whats the best practice in having multiple version of a package on my computer? I could downgrade my package to v1.5, but that would require me to upgrade my kubectl back to v1.10 every time I need to access my other cluster. I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04 (if that helps)

Comment: For me the Kubernetes API and CLI have been fairly stable, and you might see if it just works to access the older cluster using the newer `kubectl`.

Comment: David, the recent kubectl release notes discussed the backward incompatibility; if you use a 1.11 kubectl on a 1.9 cluster, you get "no such resource" errors

Answer (score 3):

They're statically linked, and have no dependencies, so there's no need to use a dependency manager for them:

```
$ curl -sSfo /usr/local/bin/kubectl-1.9 \
   https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.9.11/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
$ chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/kubectl-1.9
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. So cmiiw, but shouldn't I move the folder using $sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl ? how will my program knows which version to pick if theres 2 of the same file? Or will it just work as long as I point the code to the right config file?

Comment: You will have 2 binaries to launch: kubectl and kubectl-1.9. Where are you confusing?

Comment: Ricky, the other option is to move the binary into a separate folder, name the binary `kubectl` as expected, but just add that dir to your `PATH` so it will be found first

Comment: I'm quite new to linux so I'm still figuring out what goes where, So I tried to download the kubectl, chmod it, rename it to ```kubectl1-4``` and move it to /usr/local/bin, same place with my old kubectl. but everytime i run kubectl1-4, it just shows ```bash: /usr/local/bin/kubectl1-4: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error``` @VKR

Comment: so I tried your way, and I changed the command to ```kubectl-1.9``` to ```kubectl-1.4``` and ```v1-4-12``` according to the version i wanted, but all it gave me was an error of ```curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 614)``` @MatthewLDaniel

Comment: So for the first error, you can use `file /usr/local/bin/kubectl-14` to figure out what kind of file it really is. For the second problem, it just looks like you just don't have permission to write into the directory, so try `curl -sSfo $HOME/kubectl-1.9 ...` and ensure it works, then move it as someone with permission (likely `sudo mv ...`)